# Is there a faster way to compare these decimals?

Tags: c#, math

I have a stream of decimals and I am trying to compare the most recent decimal to the difference of the last 6 decimals, I may increase this number

I have the following `class`

```
public class CompareRandom
{
    private const decimal DIFFERENCE = 1.8m;

    public decimal a;
    public decimal b;
    public decimal c;
    public decimal d;
    public decimal e;
    public decimal f;
    public decimal g;

    public bool Compare(decimal num)
    {
        this.g = this.f;
        this.f = this.e;
        this.e = this.d;
        this.d = this.c;
        this.c = this.b;
        this.b = this.a;
        this.a = num;

        if (b != decimal.Zero && b / DIFFERENCE > a)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (c != decimal.Zero && c / DIFFERENCE > a)
        {

            return true;
        }

        if (d != decimal.Zero && d / DIFFERENCE > a)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (e != decimal.Zero && e / DIFFERENCE > a)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (f != decimal.Zero && f / DIFFERENCE > a)
        {
            return true;
        }

        if (g != decimal.Zero && g / DIFFERENCE > a)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I initialize it as volatile

```
volatile static CompareRandom CompareRandom = new CompareRandom();
```

Then I call `CompareRandom.Compare(value)` synchronously as part of a loop that updates every `1ms` to compare the values.

The part I am the most interested in knowing if there is a faster way to do is this part

```
    this.g = this.f;
    this.f = this.e;
    this.e = this.d;
    this.d = this.c;
    this.c = this.b;
    this.b = this.a;
    this.a = num;
```

A successful answer will demonstrate a faster execution of the method `Compare`

See if you can make it faster:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/tLw8qM

https://dotnetfiddle.net/jd0bSF

Comment: Using a `decimal` array might make your code easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Could you please formulate what you are trying to compute here? What exactly is the task?

Comment: I have a stream of decimals and I am trying to compare the most recent decimal to the difference of the last 6 decimals

Comment: Please write this in your question.

Comment: I would use a LinkedList<decimal>

Comment: I'm trying to a first in first out kind of thing since I am already in a loop

Comment: So a Queue<decimal>?

Comment: If your code *works* and you're looking for recommendations to *improve* it, it's probably a better fit on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever code probably does not work as it looks like OP is trying to do some multithreading with `volatile` - with that I doubt it is suitable for CR.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever thanks I didn't know that was a thing, Yes I am using this already and looking for suggestions.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov can you explain why you are so strongly against using `volatile` I don't want the compiler moving things around, yes I know I am checking the register again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to perform the division every time. Instead, *multiply* `a` by `DIFFERENCE` to obtain a threshold:

```cs
// Name changed to be more conventional
private const decimal Difference = 1.8m;

public bool Compare(decimal num)
{
    g = f;
    f = e;
    e = d;
    d = c;
    c = b;
    b = a;
    a = num;
    var threshold = num * Difference;
    return (b != decimal.Zero && b > threshold) ||
           (c != decimal.Zero && c > threshold) ||
           (d != decimal.Zero && d > threshold) ||
           (e != decimal.Zero && e > threshold) ||
           (f != decimal.Zero && f > threshold) ||
           (g != decimal.Zero && g > threshold);
};
```

As asides:

- It's odd for a `Compare` method to return `bool` rather than an integer; given that it's not the "common" meaning of `Compare`, it's probably worth renaming it for clarity
- It's *very* odd for a comparison method to change the state of an object, as this is doing (assigning to `a`) - another good reason to change the name.

Using a collection instead of separate variables would make all of this more maintainable, but I'd be surprised if it improved the *speed*.

Comment: I really like this idea of eliminating the division

Comment: @Kief: Your dotnetfiddle eliminates the comparison with zero - which means it's not equivalent to the code you showed before (suppose `b` is 0, but `num` is -1 - your original code wouldn't return true due to that, but your dotnetfiddle would).

Comment: Oh yes, very true, I'm glad you pointed that out before I realized it in an hours time

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tLw8qM

Comment: I might rename it to `CompareNext` you are right